# git-dulwich:how to merge or rebase?

Tags: python, git, merge, rebase, dulwich

I try to make a website to provide some server, such as collaborative writing at some purposed aims. But I will not to create the same wheel. So I choose git as VCS(version control system) by using [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/). Everything with dulwich is well, but I failed to find solutions to git command like 'merge' or 'rebase' to handler branches. Someone can help give some tips or examples for using dulwich to merge and rebase git branches? Thanks!

Comment: Dulwich, as of May 2013, does not yet implement merge functionality. You could write merge functionality your self, but that is non trivial.

Comment: yes，it is non trivial. thanks！

Answer (score 1):

As Gary mentions, dulwich does not provide merge or rebase support since that is nontrivial to implement well.

One option would be to shell out for merge and rebase only.

Eventually, we would like Dulwich to support use of other merge implementations such as patiencediff rather than redoing merge from scratch.